# How To replace an partial unknown string

Tags: c#, string-operations

I Need to replace (or better delete) a string, where I know the beginning and the end.
Some Characters are unknown, also the length of the string.
Of Course I could work with substring and other c# string-operations but isn't there a simple replace Wildcard Option?

```
mystring.Replace("O(*)", "");
```

Would be a nice Option.
I know that the string Begins with `O(` and Ends with `)`.
It's possible than the String Looks like `O(something);QG(anything else)`
 
Here the result should be `;QG(anything else)`

Is this possible with a simple replace?
And what About the advanced Option, that he string exists more than one time like here:
`O(something);O(someone);QG(anything else)`

Comment: Can there be something like `O(foo);QG(hello O(bar) world)` ? And if so, what would be the expected result ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at regular expressions.

The following will meet this case:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(originalString, @"O\(.*?\)", "");
```

What it means:

- `@` - switch off C# interpreting \ as escape, because otherwise the compiler will see our `\(` and try to replace it with another char like it does for \n becoming a newline (and there is no `\(` so it's a compiler error). Regex also uses \ as an escape char, so without the @ to get a slash into the string for regex to interpret as a slash to perform a regex escape, it needs a double C# slash, and that can make regex patterns more confusing
- `"` start of c# string
- `O\(` literal character `O` followed by literal character `(` - brackets have special meaning in regex, so backslash disables special meaning)
- `.*?` match zero or more of any character (lazy/pessimistic)
- `\)` literal )
- `"` end of string

`.*?` is a complex thing warrants a bit more explanation:

In regex `.` means "match any single character", and `*` means "zero or more of the previous character". In this way `.*` means "zero or more of any character".

So what's the `?` for?

By default regex `*` is "greedy" - a `.*` with eat the entire input string and then start working backwards, spitting characters back out, and checking for a match. If you had 2 in succession like you put:

```
K(hello);O(mystring);O(otherstring);L(byebye)
```

And you match it greedily, then `O\(.*\)` will match the initial O(, then consume all the input, then spit one trailing ) back out and declare it's found a match, so the `.*` matches `mystring);O(otherstring;L(byebye`

We don't want this. Instead we want it to work forwards a character at a time, looking for a matching `)`. Putting the `?` after the `*` changes from greedy mode to pessimistic(/lazy) mode, and the input is scanned forwards rather than zipping to the end and scanning backwards. This means that `O\(.*?)` matches `mystring` and then later `otherstring`, leaving a result of `K(hello);;;L(byebye)`, rather than `K(hello);`

Comment: Great Explanation... Thank you for this, I will try it out with different strings :-)